# Python script autofill html form

Tags: python, html, forms, autofill

The following script puts the required values into the single form on the webpage, but how do I make it 'submit' the values, proceed to the next page and show the page filled in as if i'd proceeded manually, please?

I've looked through the other related posts, but they don't do what I'd like.  Here is the script:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import requests
import webbrowser
url = 'https://www.example.com'
payload = {'number': '1237777', 'surname': 'xxxxxxx'}
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page   # checked form contents here
```

The html code shows the values inserted.

Comment: this is the submission. url should be the url you want to submit to

Comment: Can you go into more detail in your answer. I'm new to python.

Comment: this is not python specific, it is the way the web works. when you submit a form the browser makes a post request. `urllib2.Request(url, data)` this creates a post request too